# How to automatically start service using npm service-systemd

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm using the NPM package service-systemd to monitor a NodeJS app and restart it in case it crashes or freezes.

[NPM service-systemd](https://www.npmjs.com/package/service-systemd)

When I run 'sudo node-systemd add service-template.json', I get:

```
WARNING: wrap.bin not found
parsing ...
writing script start/stop files, logrotate.d ...
> chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/systemd-my-node-service*
writing systemd file ...
/etc/systemd/system/my-node-service.service
installing ...
> systemctl enable my-node-service.service;systemctl daemon-reload
done
```

And when I try to run 'sudo service start', the service fails. Checking 'journalctl' shows:

```
Starting service...
/usr/local/bin/systemd--start: line 2: /usr/bin/forever: No such file or directory
PID file /var/run/.pid not readable (yet?) after start.
Failed to start service
Unit .service entered failed state.
.service failed.
```

I've found some sources that suggest things like symlinks, but none of that seems to fix the issue. Any idea what's going on here?

Running this on an Odroid XU4 with Ubuntu 15.04 and NodeJS v0.10.40.

Thanks,

Comment: as an alternative of using hard-configurable systemd for applications, try to use a Docker container with restart policy: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#restart-policies-restart

Comment: Docker container is new to me. What benefit does this have over the forever/systemd node package?

Does it check if a service is frozen?

I ask because this service uses a USB 2.0 BLE dongle, that on occasion shuts off (I think this is a DC current issue from the XU4 USB hub but I need to make this thing bullet proof so I'm still looking for a solution), thus requiring a restart of the service to allow it to be turned back 'up' again by the bluetooth daemon. I'm not confident that I can always catch this with forever/systemd.

Comment: Containers are useful on application level. You can use devices too: https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/device-mapper-driver/ but it hard-configurable and less performant. I'm not sure about auto-restart if  a service is frozen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually turned out to be an issue with the version of NodeJS I was using. I started this project on the RPi2, which has issues with NodeJS v4+. Using v0.10.x is not necessary with the XU4, so I uninstalled the old version and updated to the latest. All good now.

Answer (score 0):

I've released a new version that does not require forever and with better APIs, those errors are removed